Capture chrome performance report programmatically with JavaScript?
We've been running a CPU intensive web application and there are some challenges debugging the performance issues as the hardware and CPU availability is different per user.
Although, we tried checking the performance profile and monitoring in a remote debug. We wanted to capture these information programmatically with JavaScript, when the application is running and log the information to analyse the problem more efficiently.
Does someone know an npm package which helps us capture the following information:

GPU information in chrome (Hardware acceleration is enabled or not).
CPU consumption on a specific tab.
JS heap size.
Long running tasks.
...

p.s. I've come through this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/lighthouse. But it doesn't seem to support ES module format and also doesn't provide some of the information I need in my performance metrics.
Appreciate some help here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance_API

For GPU:
Unfortunately i don't see any global api that you can use to
do that, however you can check for WebGL availability which requires Hardware
Acceleration
const isHAEnabled = () => {
    const cn = document.createElement('canvas'); /*or any canva u have*/
    const gl = cn.getContext('webgl') || canvas.cn('experimental-webgl');
    return gl && gl instanceof WebGLRenderingContext;
};

CPU Usage:
const start = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
    // Do some computation
}
const end = performance.now();
const usage = end - start; 

usage contains the usage of CPU in ms, I have used the very long loop to emulate that hard task
Memory ( Used Heap Size ):
Simply :)
const heapSize = performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize

Long running tasks:
performance.mark("start");
// your long running task eg the loop earlier
performance.mark("end");


performance.measure("codeExecutionTime", "start", "end");
const duration = performance.getEntriesByName("codeExecutionTime")[0].duration;


However for this last one, you need to change id of marks every measure,
as idk why the browser keeps old marks rather than the new

I hope this helps
